# Yii2 Boostrap ActiveForm Horizontal Layout

Tags: yii2

Good afternoon,

I am new to programming and struggling to understand Yii2 layout with Bootstrap.

What I am after is really simple, so I thought, but I can't seem to get it to remotely work.  I want to create a horizontal form with the labels in front of each input and be able to control to the width of each input.

In my current code, I have 2 simple fields, I want the first to span half of the form (`col-md-6`) and the second should span the totality of the form (`col-md-12`), but this just isn't working and I don't understand the why so I'm struggling to fix it.

Below is my view

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm; //used to enable bootstrap layout options

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Projects */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="projects-form">
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'=>$model->formName(),
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'enableError' => true,
        ]
    ]); 
?>

<h2>Project Information</h2>
<h3>General Information</h3>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
            echo $form->field(
                $model, 
                'ProjNo'
            )->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php
            echo $form->field(
                $model, 
                'ProjName'
            )->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();
?>
</div>
```

This is the `_form` view which is called within the create and update views.

What I don't quite get is why the label alignment isn't consistent because I specify a different width for the overall field and why even though I specified `col-md-12`, which should be full width from my understanding, it only seems to take about half of the available width.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

[current example of what is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQedj.jpg)

I just want the labels to line up and be able to have fields with different widths.  In the above, when I change the class, the labels change alignment.

Comment: can you add a screen grab of what you are getting and what you are trying to acheieve

Comment: updated my answer see if it helps you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `template` option under the form's `fieldConfig` option like below to specify the order of the input, label, and error-block, and these settings would be applied throughout the form for all inputs, in below configurations I am placing the label after the input you can change that if you want.

```
$form = yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin ( [ 'id' => $model->formName () ,
            'layout' => 'horizontal' ,
            'class' => 'form-horizontal' ,
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'enableError' => true ,
                'template' => '{input}{error}{label}',
    ] ] );
```

you can wrap the `{label}` and `{input}` with div like

```
'template' => '<div class="col-sm-6">{input}{error}</div>
               <div class="col-sm-3">{label}</div>',
```

and remove all the extra `HTML` from your view just wrap the `$form->field()` with `row` see below

```
$form = yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin ( [ 'id' => $model->formName () ,
                'layout' => 'horizontal' ,
                'class' => 'form-horizontal' ,
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'enableError' => true ,
                    'template' => '<div class="col-sm-6">{input}{error}</div>{label}',
        ] ] );
?>

<h2>Project Information</h2>
<h3>General Information</h3>
<div class="row">
        <?php
        echo $form->field (
                $model , 'ProjNo'
        )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true, ] );
        ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <?php
        echo $form->field (
                $model , 'ProjName'
        )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true, ] );
        ?>
</div>
```

### `EDIT`

as per discussion you do not want equally aligned labels and inputs but instead you want variable inputs and labels within each row and for doing so you need to configure the template part of the input fields separately and it can look like below if i understood correctly

[image]

you should configure your form options and field `template` options like below and remove the extra class applied on the label `col-sm-3` by assigning it `control-label` class manually

```
$form = yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin ( [ 'id' => $model->formName () ,
            'layout' => 'horizontal' ,
            'class' => 'form-horizontal' ,
            'fieldConfig' => [
                'enableError' => true ,
                'options' => [
                    'class' => ''
                ]
    ] ] );
?>
<h2>Project Information</h2>
<h3>General Information</h3>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    echo $form->field (
            $model , 'name' , [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
    )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true ] )->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] )
    ?>
    <?php
    echo $form->field (
            $model , 'price' , [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
    )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true ] )->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    echo $form->field (
            $model , 'product_subcategory' , [ 'template' => '<div class="col-sm-2">{label}</div><div class="col-sm-10">{input}{error}</div>' , ]
    )->textInput ( [ 'maxlength' => true , ] )->label ( null , [ 'class' => 'control-label' ] );
    ?>
</div>
<?php
echo yii\bootstrap\Html::submitButton ( 'Submit' );
yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end ();
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: But that makes all the fields the same and I'm looking to have the 1st half width and the 2nd full width?  I tried posting what  I came up with based on your answer, but the forum blocked my post as too long, so I'm not sure how to communicate and show you my code?! (very new to stackoverflow and finding it very frustrating to work with).

Comment: you statement **first half width and second full width** is confusing because you are using horizontal form and your label and input will be in the same row, or i am not getting what you are trying to say @StillLearning

Comment: For example. row 1, I want a label say col-sm-2 and then an input col-sm-4, so the total is col-sm-6, but row 2 I want a label say col-sm-2 and then an input col-sm-10, so the total is col-sm-12.  The idea is that I can create a layout in which I can have multiple fields in one row (Number, Street, Suite); 2 or 3 side by side.

Comment: @StillLearning are you looking for something like [**`this`**](https://imgur.com/a/z0sPWtQ)

Comment: I can't thank you enough Muhammad.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I couldn't get it to work initially, but it was my fault (syntax).  It works perfectly.  I still have soo much to learn, but thanks to you I am past this major hurdle and my form is finished and I can move on to other aspects of the application now.

Comment: you are welcome @StillLearning , do mark the answer as selected by clicking the **`✔`** sign under the answer